# What is the default date format used by pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

What is the default date format used by `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`?

The documentation says the default value for the `date_format` parameter is `None`, which is not very helpful.

I observe that its precision (fractional seconds) is variable, which is suitable for my purpose.  I am just a little worried that there might be other smart behavior built in, and that it might be influenced by regional settings.

I am using pandas version 24 at the moment.

Comment: If no `date_format` is specified, it would obey the format you have in your dataframe.

Comment: Where would I find the format in the dataframe?